# Can anyone clearify how to get tiff rating metadata in C++ or just the file rating the way Win Explore reads it?

Tags: c++, image, metadata, tiff, rating

Hey I'm completely lost when it comes to reading the tiff metadata in C++, I've looked over google and can't find any examples. All i want to do is read the rating property and output that to console i should be able to take it from there.
thanks in advance.

UPDATE
thanks folks I'll look more into the libtiff library

Looking into the libtiff folder it seems a bit overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish. Is it possible to read the "properties/details" tab of a file verse setting up the library or am I asking something extremely retarded. Again all i'm looking to find is a if there is a rating on he file or not.

Comment: 1) Learn how to do I/O in C++. 2) Learn the TIFF file format (the tagged image version, I suppose). 3) Write your console application. Alternatively, use a library that does it for you.

Comment: Use a library... really, it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, libtiff exposes all of this functionality, you just need to read the docs.

To set metadata, you have TIFFSetField

```
int
TIFFSetField(TIFF* tif, ttag_t tag, ...)
```

Likewise, to retrieve metadata you have [TIFFGetField](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/man/TIFFGetField.3tiff.html)

```
int
TIFFGetField(TIFF* tif, ttag_t tag, ...)
```

One thing to note here is if you are reading standard TIFF tags or proprietary tags.  If they are proprietary and not in the libtiff library then someone has added them on their own, in which case you need their tag declarations to incorporate into your version of libtiff (or just get theirs).  You can follow [this guide](http://www.libtiff.org/internals.html#AddingTags) if it comes to that (I've had to do it).

Answer (score 0):

There is ImageMagick which does handle TIFF images: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php you can pull the metadata using the framework it uses [libTiff](http://www.libtiff.org/) underneath, using this you should be able to pull the metadata [tags](http://www.libtiff.org/libtiff.html#Tags) using calls to `TIFFGetField` like Ed S. suggests

This is the sample usage leached from the libTiff page:

```
TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("myfile.tif", "r");
if (tif) {
uint32 imageWidth, imageLength;
uint32 tileWidth, tileLength;
uint32 x, y;
tdata_t buf;

TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &imageWidth);
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &imageLength);
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_TILEWIDTH, &tileWidth);
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_TILELENGTH, &tileLength);
buf = _TIFFmalloc(TIFFTileSize(tif));
for (y = 0; y < imageLength; y += tileLength)
    for (x = 0; x < imageWidth; x += tileWidth)
    TIFFReadTile(tif, buf, x, y, 0);
_TIFFfree(buf);
TIFFClose(tif);
}
```

there is also a list of tags that are handled by the library: http://www.libtiff.org/support.html